# How to outer shadow effect to textfield in iOS

Tags: ios, uitextview

I expected the following:
[image]

I wrote this code:

```
_nameField.layer.cornerRadius = 20;
_nameField.layer.borderWidth = 1;
_nameField.layer.borderColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;

_nameField.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:118 / 255.0 green:166 / 255.0 blue:239 / 255.0 alpha:0.60].CGColor;
_nameField.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
_nameField.layer.shadowRadius = 3.0f;
_nameField.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0;
_nameField.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.5, 0.5);
```

the result is:

[image]

How can I change my code to archive the effort wanted?
Thanks.

Comment: why don't you just use images instead of programming it?

Comment: try `_nameField.layer.cornerRadius = _nameField.frame.size.height / 2;`

Comment: @Konsy thanks. Finally, I used the image.

Comment: @Sunil, thanks. I try this sentence. But I can't get the result that I wanted.